Error in downloading driver library in connecting to MariaDB in dbeaver
When i tried to connect MariaDB, i got the below error during driver library downloading. Anyone can help how to resolve that? Thanks!

Error resolving dependencies   Cannot invoke
"org.jkiss.dbeaver.registry.maven.MavenArtifactVersion.findDependencyManagement(String,
String)" because "i" is null

Error screen
I need to connect thru' MariaDB.
